# Problem with events and deadlocks

Tags: c#

I have a problem raising events inside a lock.
The event is fired inside a property setter in a base class (when I change the property value), and i call this property in a derived class (inside a lock).
The code looks something like this:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public event EventHandler StatusChanged;

    int _status = 0;
    object lockA = new object();

    public int Status
    {
        get 
        {
            lock (lockA) { return _status; }
        }
        set
        {
            bool fireEvent = false;
            lock (lockA)
            {
                if (_status != value)
                {
                    _status = value;
                    fireEvent = true;
                }
            }

            if (fireEvent)
                StatusChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    object lockB = new object();

    public void SetStatus(int newStatus)
    {
        lock (lockB)
        {
            this.Status = newStatus;
        }
    }
}
```

The BaseClass property raises the event outside the lock to protect itself from deadlocks, but the derived class sets the new status inside its own lock. 
Since the derived class' developer may not know how the base class works, what is the best way to ensure that a deadlock cannot happen? Maybe raising events in a asynch thread?

Comment: why do you lock the property set in the derived class?

Comment: I need to lock the update code to be sure that the "check and update" operation is atomic, or else two different threads could change the property at the same time. The same problem happens if one threads calls the getter while a second thread calls the setter to change the status, the getter may not return the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

Lock in the same thread does not "lock", so there is not deadlock risk in my opinion with your code.

Comment: Yes, but we don't know what happens in the user code fired by the event: maybe it starts another thread and joins() it, and this thread calls the SetStatus() method again, causing a deadlock

Comment: @usernnnn: That would be exceptionally poor design, and I fully accept that a framework should happily support deadlock when the client messes up the threading. [1.] never do blocking operations inside an event handler [2.] never access services/UI elements from multiple threads unless explicitely designed for the purpose

Comment: You are right, I just wanted to find some way to be 100% sure a deadlock can't happen, but I guess it's impossible when you have to "depend" on some unknown user code..

Comment: @user728771 Well yes maybe the problem is eventually having the property with the lock

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess I'd have to agree that there really isn't a risk of deadlock there.  But, what do you think about using BeginInvoke() to launch the user code?

```
BeginInvoke(this, EventArgs.Empty, null, null);
```

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking about raising the event in a asynch thread and be done with that..

Answer (score 0):

When you create the BaseClass just comment it as being ThreadSafe, then if any developers implement this base class and don't see that its comments state that it is already thread safe then it's their own problem.

I thought thier might be a attribute that states a class is threadsafe but there isn't one. Sorry.